# Breaking Down Tables For Normalization 3NF

Tags: mysql, sql, normalization, database-normalization

I've just started looking into normalisation and it's completely doing my head in trying to work out how many tables should be created to hold the data which I have always just stored in one single table.  So here's how I've broken down one table so far:

```
Paper ID | Paper Name  | Category | Owner

01       | Weekly News | CAT_01  | USER_1
02       | Daily News  | CAT_01  | USER_2
03       | The Times   | CAT_02  | USER_1
```

Now is this correct normalization or should it be broken down into 3 tables, like:

```
Paper ID | Paper Name

01       | Weekly News
02       | Daily News
03       | The Times

Paper ID | Category

01       | CAT_1
02       | CAT_1
03       | CAT_2

Paper ID | Owner

01       | USER_1
02       | USER_2
03       | USER_1
```

Also, is it wrong to have blank cells in a normalized table? I have one which looks like:

```
Author ID | Last Name | First Name | Facebook | Twitter | Website

01        | Griffin   | Brian      | (url)    | (url)   | (url)
02        | Griffin   | Peter      |          | (url)   | 
03        | Griffin   | Meg        | (url)    |         | (url)
04        | Griffin   | Stewie     | (url)    | (url)   | (url)
```

Comment: blank cells are often fine.  Depending on the situation, you might want default values.

Comment: If a paper can only be in zero or one categories you can leave it in the table with Paper ID and Paper Name. If it can be in more than one, splitting it out as you've done is the correct approach. And the nulls are absolutely appropriate in this situation.

Comment: @EdGibbs I don't have a set number of categories yet but it will most likely be over 10 - Same goes for owners, 1 user can own 3 papers for example

Comment: Just to be sure I'm not misleading you: it doesn't have anything to do with the number of categories you'll have; it has to do with the number of categories a paper can belong to. If there are 1,000,000 categories but a paper can only be in one (or zero) of them, you can leave the `Category` column in your original category - it'll be easier to query then. It's only when the paper can be in more than one category that you should split the category out to another table. Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: Oh right, well in that case each paper is assigned to only one category

Answer (score 1):

In terms of Entity Relationship Modeling:

Each "entity" in the model should be represented as a row in a table. An "entity" is a person, place, thing, concept or event that can be uniquely identified, is important to the business, and we can store information about.

The attributes of an "entity" appear as columns in the table. In the case of "repeating" attributes, attributes that can appear multiple times, we can create a secondary child table.

"Normalization" does not call for breaking out every attribute into a separate table.

It's entirely valid to represent a "missing" or "unknown" attribute value with a special value; we often use the special `NULL` value to represent the absence of a value, though it's entirely valid to use any other value you choose, a zero length string, or a string such as `'N/A'`, depending on the requirements/use case.

---

In a fully "normalized" model, each and every attribute is dependent on "**the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key**".

Answer (score 1):

1. No, breaking it into three tables would just be silly.
2. It's not "wrong" to have null values under certain circumstances, but I'm concerned you have essentially one-to-many info implemented as multiple columns.  If you want to add another URL type, you will need to change the table schema, and all the code that reads it, which is not good.  You should do something more like:

> ```
> Author ID | Last Name | First Name
>
> 01        | Griffin   | Brian      
> 02        | Griffin   | Peter      
> 03        | Griffin   | Meg        
> 04        | Griffin   | Stewie     
>
> ID        | Author ID | URL Type  | URL
>
> 01        | 01        | Facebook  | (url)      
> 02        | 01        | Twitter   | (url)      
> 03        | 01        | Website   | (url)        
> 04        | 02        | Twitter   | (url)
> ```

Put a unique index on Author ID + URL Type if you want to prevent an author from having two Twitter URLs.

Comment: Thanks for laying that out for me. My main concern is that there will be a lot of `joins` with using multiple tables - Won't this slow the scripts down? I've always used ane table to store as much data as I cna and used php to filter it out

Comment: Databases are *designed* to join tables.  I guarantee a DB join is orders of magnitude faster than slamming everything into memory and letting PHP sort it out.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it should be

Papers Table

```
Paper ID | Paper Name  | Category_Id | Owner_id

01       | Weekly News | CAT_01      | USER_1
02       | Daily News  | CAT_01      | USER_2
03       | The Times   | CAT_02      | USER_1
```

Categories table

```
Category ID | Category name     
1           |  Category_a
```

Owners Table

```
Owner ID | Owner Name | 
1        | Owner X
```

What your basic aim should be is to move each entity to its own table. Each entity will have its own attributes which should be added in that particular entities table.

Now for example a paper belongs to a particular category. All you need to do is refer to the category id from the categories table in the paper table. The paper table doesn't need to have a category name  column. the rest of categories data can be gathered using the reference to the category id

Also it is not wrong to have blank cells in your table. I'd suggest not to overcomplicate things. Though normalisation does sound esoteric to begin with, database design is more of common sense. Just think about it, you have the option for allowing a user to login with Facebook. You know that some people will take that option and so you will have to store their Facebook id's somewhere. On the other hand there will be some people who will not want to log in via Facebook and so their facebook_id columns will be empty.

Some more to read :
[Intro to Normalization](http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/tech-resources/articles/intro-to-normalization.html)

Comment: Oh right, I see. As you can probably tell I'm finding it a little hard to grasp the normalization concept

Comment: It is a little intimidating in the beginning. Read up some more and soon you'll have the aha moment.

Comment: Thanks, I've bookmarked that link to take a look at a little ater on. I would actually like to use the facebook & twitter logins at some point so I'd like to get the tables sorted out so I can make that happen

Comment: yea i'd suggest to first completely understand the concept before you actually start build your app. Everything basically depends on your database.

Answer (score 1):

## 1

Assume owner have three values firstname, lastname and address.

In this case, your design might look like,

```
Paper ID | Paper Name  | Category | FirstName | LastName | Address
```

This is poor design since a owner can own more than one book. In that situation the details of owner will be repeated. To avoid that, you should have two relations namely Paper and Owner

Paper:

```
Paper ID | Paper Name  | Category | OwnerID
```

Owner:

```
OwnerID | FirstName | LastName | Address
```

You can divide the relation (table) into multiple relation as long as it follows NormalForms. You dont need to divide the relation as you mentioned.

Read Normal Forms.

## 2

Its valid to have null values in columns to represent empty. But it is fine if number of columns is small. If the number columns is large say 10 but the author hardly have 2 to 3 url's maximum, in this case follow the below structure.

Relation 1: Socialsites

```
 sid <primary key> | Name     | URL
 ------------------------------------
 1                 |Facebook  | <url>
 2                 |Twitter   | <url>
```

Relation 2: Author

```
 AuthorID<PK> | Last Name | First Name
 -----------------------------------
 01           | Griffin   | Brian
```

Relation 3: authorsitemapping

```
 AuthorID | Sid
 --------------
 01       | 1
 02       | 2
```

Here {AuthorID,Sid} is primary key. AuthorID references Author and Sid references Socialsites.

Answer (score 1):

The rearrangements you and other answers describe are not necessary. They have nothing to do with normalizaiton.

In particular you do not need to introduce ids and you do not need to move columns into separate base tables.

Normalization does not apply to tables with NULL. But your use of NULL is a typical SQL idiom corresponding to a normalized design with a table instead of each of nullable column. So changing your design would not be for reasons of normalization.

Whether you should rearrange your tables depends on information you haven't given, namely your FDs and JDs.

Normalization has nothing to do with entities or number of columns. Normalization requires that you determine "functional dependencies" (FDs) (ie when a column is a function of other columns) and "join dependencies" (JDs) (ie when a table can be expressed as the join of projections of it). Then you determine "candidate keys" (CKs) (ie column sets of which all other columns are functions but that don't contain any smaller such sets). A table is normalized (to 5NF) when all its JDs are "implied by" its candidate keys (ie if it is a join of projections then each projection's column set is some key column sets plus zero or more columns that are functions of those key column sets but of no smaller subsets). You can't normalize if you do not learn the requisite notions and techniques.